# Is there such a thing as (LDL) cholesterol half life?

Tags: cholesterol

Suppose that—post holiday pot roast, cheese, and cookie eating that borders on indulgence—your January 2nd blood test reveals that your (LDL) cholesterol is high.

No surprise there. You were asking for it.

Now you get back to a more careful diet. You specify your maximum daily tolerable saturated-fat intake, and you stop eating anything with saturated fats once you hit that limit.

How many weeks do you have to wait before a subsequent blood test so that you can reasonably assert that your diet is now acceptable?

In short, is there such a thing as a (LDL) cholesterol half life?

### Understood that:

- (LDL) cholesterol is synthesized by homo-sapiens.
- (LDL) cholesterol is used for multiple cell functions, including bile synthesis.
- Even with a zero-fat diet (a bad idea by itself), the plateau for (LDL) cholesterol will never be zero.